# Curve of constant curvature and zero torsion is contained in a circumference.

Tags: differential-geometry

The problem states: 
A curve $b(s)$ with  unitary speed is part of a circumference if and only if $k>0$ and it's torsion is equal to zero.
I'm having struggles with the problem and I would like some hints please

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: Basically since the beginning, I'm lost in this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\alpha = \sigma +k^{-1} N$. By virtue of the Frenet-Serret equations and because there is zero torsion we get $N' = -k T$ so $\alpha' = T - k^{-1}k T =0$. It follows that $\alpha$ is a constant point in space, call it $p$.

This gives that $\lVert \sigma-p \rVert = k^{-1}$ everywhere and because $\sigma$ has zero torsion, $\sigma$ is contained in a circle of radius $k^{-1}$ centered at $p$ on the plane $B\cdot (x-p)=0$ where $B$ is the (constant) binormal to $\sigma$.